# Criação de imagens GIF

Tags: imagem

Alguém sabe como criar uma imagem tipo GIF como essa que está na home da [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/assets/images/create-droplet-v5-e512defa.gif)

Answer (score 1):

A página provavelmente usa uma ferramenta que captura a tela e cria um GIF animado. Uma que funciona relativamente bem é https://github.com/NickeManarin/ScreenToGif.